# return true in nested function part of new Image() .onload to verify image exist from url?

Tags: javascript

How can I **return true** when function is run inside function part of new Image() .onload, in order to verify if a url is a valid image?

```
var valid = false;
checkImage('https://example.com/image.png')
console.log(valid) //always false at first run

function checkImage(url) {

  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function () {
    if (this.width > 0) {
            valid = true;
    }
  }
  image.onerror = function() {
        valid = false;
  }
  image.src = url;
}
```

I also tried setting a global variable which doesn't work,Or any other way to return true / false back via checkImage(url) ?

Got this initial solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55880263/8719001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(async () => {
  let valid = await checkImage('https://example.com/image.png')
  console.log(valid)
})();

async function checkImage(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    const image = new Image()
    image.onload = () => resolve(!!image.width)
    image.onerror = () => resolve(false)
    image.src = url
  })
}
```

Comment: Should be `resolve(image.width > 0)` instead of `image.width && resolve(true)` to avoid a pending promise never resolving.

Comment: Thanks Andrew that worked instantly, for some reason @Sheraff didn't. What does `resolve(!!image.width)` do? Always return true if image has content/data? (I take it that onload must only run when the image was possible to load, meaning url exists and file type is an image type. Also wondering about the double !!).

Comment: @Markus `!!image.width` is an idiom which returns true if `image.width` is non-zero, or false otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Following your code example you'll need to wrap your result in a `Promise`, which is an object made for "returning a result later":

```js
function checkImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      if (this.width > 0) {
        resolve()
      } else {
        reject()
      }
    }
    image.onerror = reject
    image.src = url;
  })
}

const valid = await checkImage('https://example.com/image.png')
```

Alternatively, a simpler way of doing this would be to use `fetch` if your only goal is to check for the file's existence (and not necessarily checking whether it works as an image):

```js
const exists = await fetch(url, {method: 'HEAD'})
  .then(response => response.status === 200)
```

Comment: note that this approach (the first of the two pieces of code) throws an exception rather than setting valid to false

Comment: @AndrewParks That's a good thing to point out indeed. Crucial for someone not used to promises.

Comment: indeed I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules` error while @AndrewParks code worked instantly. I do want to check if url is image as I'm displaying the image and otherwise reject the url from an input field.

Comment: FYI out of curiosity I tried your code with adding `async` before function and call it same way as Andrew did `(async () => {` but didn't work neither, not exactly sure why. I'll accept Andrews answer thanks, but would be good to know what I was missing with your code, appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation about using Promise! Learned something new, love it.